# TypeError when parsing a string to a Sympy equation

Tags: python, typeerror, sympy

I'm trying to parse the a string to a sympy expression using the sympy method sympy.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr.

This is the problematic string:
`'0*1(A*(n-1)**2+B*(n-1)+C)+1*1(A*(n-2)**2+B*(n-2)+C)+0.5*n**2+0.5*n-(A*n**2+B*n+C)'`

In contrast, I have another equation string, which is parsed without problems:

```
'a_1 * (-0.500000000000000)**0+a_2 * (0.500000000000000)** - 1'
```

The error message I get when parsing the problematic string is the following:

`eq = parse_expr(eq)
  File "###\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sympy\parsing\sympy_parser.py", line 965, in parse_expr
    return eval_expr(code, local_dict, global_dict)
  File "###\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\sympy\parsing\sympy_parser.py", line 878, in eval_expr
    code, global_dict, local_dict)  # take local objects in preference
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'One' object is not callable`

I know the problematic string is much more complex, but I can't find any differences in uses of operators. I hope anyone can tell me why this string gives problems whereas the previous one does not.

Comment: print that object `One` and see if it's a callable first. the problem might not be with your string

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for posting here, I just missed '*' in between variables and expressions between brackets. For example, this bit was problematic:
`0*1(A*(n-1)**2+B*(n-1)+C)`
After changing it to `0*1*(A*(n-1)**2+B*(n-1)+C)`
The parsing succeeded.